# How many regions can be selected in a chess board?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard, polyomino

How many regions can be selected in a 8 by 8 chess board?

Definition of region: A region is a set of cells that are all connected together(by edge). i.e. a possible region:

[image]

I want to run(or do complexity analysis for) a backtrack algorithm, and need to know the number of possible regions.

Comment: My first try (**which might lead nowhere**) is to count the # of regions possible that are wholly contained in a $1 \times 1$ rectangle.  Then, assuming that I have counted the # of regions possible that are contained in an $a \times b$ rectangle, I would then try to count the # of regions possible that are contained in **both** an $a \times (b+1)$ rectangle and an $(a+1) \times b$ rectangle.  Then, I would try to count the # of regions possible that are contained in an $(a+1) \times (b+1)$ rectangle.  The intent would be to look for patterns.

Comment: Another try is counting with a program the number of regions for a $1 \times 1$ square, then $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$, etc. and then search for the sequence in OEIS. The first two terms, if I am not wrong, should be $1, 14$, but two terms are not enough for a meaningful search.

Comment: I think you can work it out from http://oeis.org/A292357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you are looking for is $51016818604894742$ and it is part of [OEIS sequence A059525](http://oeis.org/A059525).